# Why must we use the closed unit disk?

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

Exercise 8.24 from Beck's *A First Course in Complex Analysis* is as follows:

Prove that if $f$ is entire and Im$(f)$ is constant in the closed unit disk then $f$ is constant.

Maybe I'm missing something because as far as I'm aware, my solution does not require the unit disk to be closed. Here is my attempt:

Since Im$(f)$ is constant in the closed unit disk, we know
$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 0$$
and by the Cauchy-Riemann equations, we also know
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = 0.$$

These are true when $|z|\le 1$. Because $f$ is entire, we can write it as a series centered at $0$.
$$f(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}z^n$$
$$= f(0) + \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}z^n$$
$$= f(0)\text{, when }|z|<1.$$

But Corollary 8.9 implies that this series converges for $R=\infty$, hence $f$ is constant in $\mathbb{C}$.

Corollary 8.9 says the following:

If $G$ is a region, $z_0 \in G$, and $f$ is holomorphic in $G$, then $f$ can be expanded into a power series centered at $z_0$ whose radius of convergence is at least the distance of $z_0$ to $\partial G$.

Why does the exercise posed use the **closed** unit disk?

Comment: You're correct.  Of course, the same proof works for any disk of radius $> 0$, and any such disk contains a closed disk of any smaller radius, so there's no great loss of generality.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. All I needed was a disk with any positive radius.